# Type safety Hashtable

Tags: java, serialization

I am deserializing a `Hashtable` into a `Hashtable` instance using casting and i get this warning: `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Hashtable<Date,String>`.

The code: 
`list = ((Hashtable<Date,String>)oos.readObject());`

Is there a way to solve this warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: no, there isn't.

You see, the signature of that [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()) says: it returns **Object**:

> public final Object readObject()

Thus you *must* cast here. And thus there is **no** other way than suppressing the warning.

And there is also no other way. Keep in mind: the idea is that you can write *any* kind of java object into such streams. And thus you can "pull" any kind of object from it, too. Thus Object is the only return type that makes sense here.

Of course, with Java generics, the result *could* be some T, or some T that is further restricted. But then that would still be compile time only, with *zero* guarantees that things turn out as expected at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

```
    Object obj = oos.readObject();
    if (obj instanceof Hashtable) {
        list = ((Hashtable<?, ?>) obj);
        final Date dateKey = Date.from(Instant.parse("2019-05-01T00:00:00Z"));
        Object value = list.get(dateKey);
        if (value == null) {
            System.out.println("No value found for key " + dateKey);
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("Value read from list was " + value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("list contained unexpected value type " + value.getClass());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unexpected type read: " + obj.getClass());
    }
```

There are two steps:

- Check that the object read from `oos` is a `Hashtable` (BTW a very old class that we’re generally not using anymore).
- Check that the `Hashtable` contains `Date` keys and `String` values (BTW `Date` is another very old class that we’re generally not using anymore).

At runtime we can check whether the object read from `oos` is a `Hashtable` through `obj instanceof Hashtable`, but due to the way Java generics work we cannot check whether is is a `Hashtable<Date, String>`. Therefore we just cast to `Hashtable<?, ?>`. The compiler can see the `instanceof` check and will not issue any warning because of this cast.

The `get` method of the `Hashtable` accepts any `Object` as argument (for historical reasons), so there is no problem passing a `Date` to it. Our second check is of the value returned from `get`: we want to know whether this is a `String` as expected. If it is, we can safely cast to `String` (not shown in the snippet).

If the `Hashtable` didn’t contain a mapping for the `Date` provided, `get` returns `null`. This in turn might either be because the `Hashtable` key type was not `Date` as expected or simply because our particular `Date` was not present as a key.